# How to use LogiCORE DSP48 Macro?

Tags: signal-processing, fpga, xilinx

I want to learn how to use LogiCORE DSP48 Macro. I'm reading the Xilinx documentation but I cannot understand well how to start my first design with DSP48 Macro. Can anyone help me to make a simple design to get a better understanding of this IP core please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You normally do not 'use' a DSP48 macro or 'start a design' with it. It is inferred by the synthesis tool by e,g, using a multiply operator.

Comment: You can just use `y <= a * b` in VHDL, if e.g. both operators and the result are of type `unsigned`. Synthesis will automatically use DSP blocks. Depending on you chip, it might be a `DSP48` primitive.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases you would use DSP48 by writing Verilog/VHDL expressions containing add, subtract, and multiply.

> x = a * b + c

A problem with the above expression is that the multiplication and addition take place in a single cycle. You can run the expression at a higher frequency if the operation could be pipelined. Vivado can sometimes retime these expressions across registers in order to make use of the DSP48 pipeline registers.

However, I understand wanting to use the DSP48 directly. You instantiate DSP48's just like other RTL modules. The ports, parameters, and behaviors are described in the DSP Slice User Guide for the FPGA logic that you are using.

```
 wire [47:0] c;
 wire [24:0] a;
 wire [17:0] b;
 DSP48E1#() dsp(
     .a(a),
     .b(b),
     .c(c),
     .p(x),
     .opmode(5),
     .alumode(0)
 );
```

This instance is copied from one of my inner-product implementations. It is fully pipelined because I was aiming for 500MHz operation. Only achieved 400MHz due to other combinational paths.

For Xilinx 7 Series:
   [DSP48E1 Slice User Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug479_7Series_DSP48E1.pdf)

For Xilinx Ultrascale:
   [DSP48E2 Slice User Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug579-ultrascale-dsp.pdf)